# Xamarin - Databinding in a ViewCell

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin

How are controls in a Xamarin Forms ViewCell bound

For example, when I add the following databinding to a Label, which is part of the  View of a ViewCell, it binds to the BindingContext of the ViewCell (I presume). How is this logic implemented? Does the TextProperty property of the label query the ViewCell's DataContext?

```
lbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "Time", stringFormat: "{0:dd MMM}"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer can be found here: https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-data-binding/

> While the BindingContext property of each target object can be individually set, this isn’t necessary. BindingContext is a special property that’s inherited by all its children. Therefore, when the BindingContext on the ContentPage is set to DetailsViewModel, all of the children of the ContentPage have the same BindingContext, and can bind to public properties of DetailsViewModel